# UITableView with pull to refresh and locked cells like UltraVisual

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to make something similar to what UltraVisual for iOS already does. I'd like to make my pull-to-refresh be in a cell in-between other cells.

I think the following GIF animation explains it better:

[image: UltraVisual pull-to-refresh]

It looks like the first cell fades out when pulling up, while when you pull down and you're at the top of the table, it adds a new cell right below the first one and use it as the pull-to-refresh.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote this one for UV. Its actually way simpler than you're describing. Also, for what its worth, this view was written as a `UICollectionView`, but the logic still applies to `UITableView`.

There is only one header cell. Durring the 'refresh' animation, I simply set the content inset of the `UICollectionView` to hold it open. Then when I've finished with the reload, I animate the content inset back to the default value.

As for the springy fixed header, there's a couple of ways you can handle it. Quick and dirty is to use a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and modify the attributes in `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`

Here's some pseudo code assuming your first cell is the sticky header:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    if ([self contentOffsetIsBelowZero]) {
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in layoutAttributes) {
        if (attributes.indexPath.item == 0) {
            CGPoint bottomOrigin = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(attributes.frame));
            CGPoint converted = [self.collectionView convertPoint:bottomOrigin toView:self.collectionView.superview];
            height = MAX(height, CGRectGetHeight(attributes.frame));
            CGFloat offset = CGRectGetHeight(attributes.frame) - height;
            attributes.frame = CGRectOffset(CGRectSetHeight(attributes.frame, height), 0, offset);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to write a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and calculate the `CGRect's` manually.

And finally, the 'fade out' is really nothing more than setting the opacity of the objects inside the first cell as it moves off screen. You can calculate the position of the cell on screen during `- (void)applyLayoutAttributes…` and set the opacity based on that.

Finally, something to note: In order to do any 'scroll based' updates with `UICollectionView`, you'll need to make sure `- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds` returns `YES`. You can do a simple optimisation check like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    BOOL shouldInvalidate = [super shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:newBounds];

    if ([self contentOffsetIsBelowZero]) {
        shouldInvalidate = YES;
    }

    return shouldInvalidate;
}
```

Again this is mostly pseudo code, so re-write based on your own implementation. Hope this helps!